# Why would this thread fail to acquire the mmap_sem semaphore?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, semaphore

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem in my kernel:

khungtask panic was thrown due to a stuck process. The process which triggered the panic has four threads. Two threads stuck trying to a acquire the `mmap_sem` semaphore. And the other two were waiting on a user-space mutex.

Here is the stack trace for the first one:

```
crash> set 14789
    PID: 14789
COMMAND: "dumper:du"
   TASK: ffff8801a434c140  [THREAD_INFO: ffff8801ecd7c000]
    CPU: 0
  STATE: TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE
crash> bt
PID: 14789  TASK: ffff8801a434c140  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "dumper:du"
 #0 [ffff8801ecd7dda8] __schedule at ffffffff8143fa09
 #1 [ffff8801ecd7de50] schedule at ffffffff8143fb95
 #2 [ffff8801ecd7de60] rwsem_down_failed_common at ffffffff81440fdf
 #3 [ffff8801ecd7dec0] rwsem_down_write_failed at ffffffff81441024
 #4 [ffff8801ecd7ded0] call_rwsem_down_write_failed at ffffffff812167c3
 #5 [ffff8801ecd7df20] sys_mprotect at ffffffff810f968e
 #6 [ffff8801ecd7df80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff81447f42
    RIP: 00000031dfce5377  RSP: 00007fff3c2b6408  RFLAGS: 00013202
    RAX: 000000000000000a  RBX: ffffffff81447f42  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: 0000000000001000  RDI: 00007f95310a1000
    RBP: 00000031e061c360   R8: 0000000000000019   R9: 0000000000000008
    R10: 00000031dfa20000  R11: 0000000000003246  R12: 0000000000000003
    R13: 0000000000000000  R14: 00007f95318a19c0  R15: 0000000000800000
    ORIG_RAX: 000000000000000a  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

And here is the stack trace from the second one:

```
crash> set 14791
    PID: 14791
COMMAND: "dumper:du"
   TASK: ffff8801eda161c0  [THREAD_INFO: ffff8801f0fa2000]
    CPU: 1
  STATE: TASK_RUNNING
crash> bt
PID: 14791  TASK: ffff8801eda161c0  CPU: 1   COMMAND: "dumper:du"
 #0 [ffff8801f0fa3d88] __schedule at ffffffff8143fa09
 #1 [ffff8801f0fa3e30] schedule at ffffffff8143fb95
 #2 [ffff8801f0fa3e40] rwsem_down_failed_common at ffffffff81440fdf
 #3 [ffff8801f0fa3ea0] rwsem_down_write_failed at ffffffff81441024
 #4 [ffff8801f0fa3eb0] call_rwsem_down_write_failed at ffffffff812167c3
 #5 [ffff8801f0fa3f00] sys_mmap_pgoff at ffffffff810f8de4
 #6 [ffff8801f0fa3f70] sys_mmap at ffffffff8101280e
 #7 [ffff8801f0fa3f80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff81447f42
    RIP: 00000031dfce531a  RSP: 00007f95330a30c8  RFLAGS: 00013246
    RAX: 0000000000000009  RBX: ffffffff81447f42  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000000003  RSI: 0000000000001000  RDI: 0000000000000000
    RBP: 0000000000001000   R8: 00000000ffffffff   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 0000000000000022  R11: 0000000000003246  R12: ffffffff8101280e
    R13: ffff8801f0fa3f78  R14: 0000000000000003  R15: 0000000000040000
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000009  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

I see that the first one was TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE, and the second one was TASK_RUNNING. Why would that be?

Obviously, the first one which was TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE is the one that triggered the panic. But, why would both fail to acquire the semaphore?

I do not understand this.

Comment: What kernel version do you use? I guess `rwsem_down_write_failed` just corresponds to slow path, when there is a *contention* on the rw mutex field(s). Aside from difference in task state between the processes, there is difference in RIP registers.

Comment: I am using uek. What clues does the difference in RIP give you?

Comment: `What clues does the difference in RIP give you?` - Probably, the processes are **at different instructions** in `__schedule` call. So difference in task state is not surprising. As for your another question, `But, why would both fail to acquire the semaphore?` - `mmap_sem` may be locked by other process, unrelated to "dumper:du". This semaphore protects memory mapping, so it is locked whenever mapping is being read or being changed.

Comment: ok...I agree on the RIP issue. But which process would be interested in locking another process's mmap_sem?

Comment: btw, I added debug code to the semaphore. The debug code saves the pid of the thread that 'down_write' s the semaphore. I did not add anything for 'down_read'. And I see that added field is set to 0. So, most likely it was being held for read.